# Python Inheritance suitability of using subclass to produce plot after setting plot properties in parent

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to write a simple Python matplotlib plotting Class that will set up formatting of the plot as I would like. To do this, I am using a class and a subclass. The parent generates an axis and figure, then sets all axis properties that I would like. Then the `child` generates the plot itself - scatter plot, line, etc. - and saves the plot to an output file.

Here is what I have come up with for the purposes of this question (the plot itself is based on [this code](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/simple_plot.html)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class myplot():

    def __init__(self,dims,padd):
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.5, 11))
        self.ax = self.fig.add_axes(dims)
        self.pad = padd

    def ax_prop(self):
        self.ax.set_axisbelow(True)
        self.ax.tick_params(axis='x', pad=self.pad, which='both')

class plotter(myplot):
    def __init__(self,dims,padd,x,y):
        myplot.__init__(self,dims,padd)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def mk_p(self):
        self.ax.plot(self.x, self.y, linestyle = '-')
        plt.savefig('Outfile.png', facecolor=self.fig.get_facecolor(), dpi = 300)
        plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
    propr = [0.60, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25]; padding =5 
    plt_instance = myplot(propr,padding)
    plt_instance.ax_prop()
    pl_d = plotter(propr,padding,x,y)
    pl_d.mk_p()
```

I'm tying to base this on the following:

```
The child must have all the properties of the parent.
```

Therefore, the `child` class `plotter()` must inherit the:

```
ax, and all its customized properties
fig
```

from the parent (`myplot()`) class. The following may change in the `Child` class:

1. type of plot - scatter, line, etc.
2. any properties of the type of plot - `markersize`, `linestyle`, etc.

but the `matplotlib` figure and axis objects (`fig`,`ax`) will always be required before plotting an input set of numbers.

**Question:**

Is this a *correct* usage of Python inheritance or is the child class superfluous in this case? If so, was there a place where the reasoning for a subclass was not consistent with object oriented programming (I'm having difficulty convincing myself of this)?

Comment: Why not just create a function that creates the figure and a second function which draws on it? In general you should prefer composition to inheritance. Inheritance should imply an "is a" relationship. Is "plotter" a "myplot"?

Comment: No. it is not. Yeah, that pretty much answers my question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You basically just explained right here. I didn't understand this concept.

Comment: Also you should be inheriting your classes from `object` if they don't have a specific base type. In Python 3 you can omit the parentheses after the name of the class entirely if you like.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by `object`? Do you have an example?

Comment: You should use `class myplot(object)`. Not subclassing from `object` will declare an [old-style class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1203997/478079), which is something you do not want. Old-style classes were removed in Python 3, but some people still inherit from `object`, so it is optional.

Comment: @WR:  You should accept Zac's answer instead.  Although your subclass does violate the Liskov Substitution Principle, it is due to semantics, not method signature.

Comment: @WR You might also want to give [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) a read. For a quick taste, look at the code in my answer to see some of the code style fixes I made, particularly in your `if __name__ == '__main__':` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue is that your subclass violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  Also see [here](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2009/02/11/solid-development-principles-in-motivational-pictures/) for nice pictures of SOLID principles.  You can't substitute an instance of `myplot` for `plotter`, since `plotter`'s method signature is different.  You should be able to substitute in a subclass instead of the base class.  Because the signature is different, you cannot.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. I just missed it totally before. Thanks.

Comment: Child classes extending the functionality of a base class isn't a violation of LSP.

Comment: @ZacCrites:  You are correct.  I have fixed the reasoning (His subclass still violates the LSP principle, but not for the reason I originally gave).

Comment: @Gerrat Is it? The constructors have different signatures, but there's nothing wrong with that. Do you mean that he's calling `mk_p` on an instance of `plotter` when he should really only be calling methods defined on the base class interface?

Comment: @ZacCrites:  The constructors do have different signatures, and there `is` something wrong with that.  Because of that fact, you cannot use a `plotter` in place of a `myplot` (which is what LSP demands - see either article I linked, or any other resource).  The extra `mk_p` method is ok - it wouldn't affect the substitution.

Comment: @Gerrat What's wrong with that? Once the object is created they can be used interchangably. If you had different `Logger` implementations, such as `FileLogger(string filepath)`, `DatabaseLogger(string usename, password, database_name, hostname)`, `ConsoleLogger()`, `WebServiceLogger(string username, password)`, obviously these all don't have the same constructors. The point of LSP is that each of these implementations can be *used* in the same way after they are created. If they all implement the `Logger` interface then it doesn't matter how they are created.

Comment: @ZacCrites:  It appears the internet agrees with you.  I do a lot more functional programming than OO-based, and it appears my instincts with this were wrong.  I would just delete my answer at this point rather than changing it again to point to the semantics of subclasses, but I can't since it's currently the accepted answer.  Feel free to provide your own answer to this.

Comment: Wow, great points all around. I don't want to make this a long discussion but, I had asked the OP for clarification as to whether `plotter` would be a child of `myplot` the same way that `Parrot` would be the child of `Pet` as shown [here](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/). I thought I had it perfectly set up but couldn't quite justify it to myself, which is why I had asked the question. I can see both points of view presented here. Thanks for all this info.

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer composition to inheritance wherever possible. I would make a function that creates the plot and another that draws on it.

```
def create_plot(dims, pad):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.5, 11))
    ax = fig.add_axes(dims)
    ax.set_axisbelow(True)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', pad=pad, which='both')
    return fig

def draw_plot(fig, x, y, outfile):
    fig.axes[0].plot(x, y, linestyle='-')
    plt.savefig(outfile, facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), dpi=300)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)
    dims = [0.60, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25]
    padding = 5

    outfile = 'Outfile.png'
    fig = create_plot(dims, padding)
    draw_plot(fig, x, y, outfile)
```